# Python Error: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, api, screen-scraping

I am using finnhub to extract stock market data and I keep running into this error. Here is the code segment where the error occurs. Stringer represents the stock market ticker. For example, Apple would be AAPL. The URL changes based on the ticker :

```py
def getNewsSentiment (stringer):
    print ("\n")
    part='https://finnhub.io/api/v1/news-sentiment?symbol' +stringer+ 'token=<TOKEN>'
    r = requests.get(part)
    print (r.json())
```

Method call: `getNewsSentiment(stringer)`

Comment: what does `print(r.text())` look like? Are you getting a response? Is it the response you're expecting?

Comment: Error: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: `r.text`, sorry

Comment: It says API limit reached

Comment: welp, that's most likely your issue – you're not getting a valid response because you've reached your limit already. so you won't get a valid response